# Can adding extra const qualifications break functionality (assuming compilation went fine)?

Tags: c++, testing, compilation, constants

As I try to apply const-correctness for my own code, I often have to add `const` qualifications to function definitions in other modules (written by other programmers) in order to use those functions in my own code. ([see here on back-patching const-correctness](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#retrofitting-const))

I always thought that if everything compiles fine, this could impossibly lead to broken functionality as `const` labels only matter at compile time.

Yet, the other day one of my colleagues insisted that I should rerun all automated tests before I commit code with added `const` labels, where I thought it was sufficient that such code compiled.

Does he have a point? Is there a way that applying const-correctness could break existing functionality ?

**Edit:** It is maybe important to note that, generally, I only have to do this for pointer parameters of functions (e.g. `Something getSomething(Object* pObj)` to `Something getSomething(const Object* pObj)`. I do not change return types or method constness as this is not a problem for client code.

Comment: All the answers you got so far seem to be talking about adding `const` to *variables.* I understood your question as adding `const` qualification to *member functions.* Can you clarify a bit on what types of `const` you're adding?

Comment: If you have tests you should always run them

Comment: If you don't have tests then you should always create them.

Comment: Hmm, is there any tool to scan code and point out where you could/should add `const`?

Comment: Of course, I always run tests when I commit my own code. But running all tests takes about 3 hours, which seems like a lot for adding a few const labels

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As const method may differ than non const one

```
class C
{
public:
    int& get() { return i; }    
    int get() const { return i; }
private:
    int i = 42;
};
```

you may have different bahavior:

```
C c;

auto&& p1 = c.get();
auto&& p2 = c.get();
assert(&p1 == &p2); // true
```

whereas

```
const C c;

auto&& p1 = c.get();
auto&& p2 = c.get();
assert(&p1 == &p2); // not true.
```

Comment: Thanks for including a concrete example

Comment: Well, that is `true` and `does not compile`.  ;)  You can get it to work, but not with a raw `&`: `&` cannot be applied to a temporary `int` directly.  You can capture `c.get()` into references and then test: `const int& a = c.get(); const int& b = c.get(); assert(&a==&b);`

Comment: @Yakk: Idea was there :) Fixed anyway.

Answer (score 15):

They do indeed have a point.

1. If you cast away `const`ness from a variable that was originally `const`, then the program behaviour is undefined. You risk introducing that into your code if you add `const` qualifications.
2. You might unintentionally switch function *overloading* for function *overriding*.
3. Passing an anonymous temporary to a function that takes a `const`  reference is defined, but if the function takes a non-`const` reference then the behaviour is undefined. Many compilers permit the non-`const` (possibly accidentally although some even go as far as calling it an *extension*). Ostensibly, you're doing everyone a favour in fixing this, but you might be removing an undefined-behaviour construct that is relied upon at runtime.
4. The C++ standard does **not** insist that `sizeof(T*) == sizeof(const T*)`. Your class' v-table layout *could* be different on your making a non-`const` to `const` parameter switch. Granted, it's unlikely, but you *must* test.

In summary, you *must* test these changes.

Comment: For case (3) such code should be ill-formed, not undefined. VC++ is broken. And which are compilers are included in "many compilers"?

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with your answer but, to clarify, does (1) imply that using `const_cast` always yields undefined behaviour?

Comment: Not at all: If the variable was originally non-const, and you receive it as const, you are allowed to cast it back to non-const. Of course, casting to const is always fine.

Comment: You're being [challenged](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33869832/could-it-be-the-case-that-sizeoft-sizeofconst-t#comment55503160_33869976) on point 4.

Comment: Hum. There's *no way* that the standard insists that sizeof(char*) is the same as sizeof(const char*). That's one counter-example.

Comment: @Bathsheba "3.9.2.3. Pointers to cv-qualified and cv-unqualified versions (3.9.3) of layout-compatible types shall have the same value representation and alignment requirements (3.11)"

Comment: I'm confident you're correct for non-PODs, by what about pointers to PODs?

Comment: Why would you think so? Every type is layout-compatibile with itself.

Comment: @AviGinsburg, In regard to the challenge, ElderBug's comment on the first answer is crucial.  In short, the difference is not supposed to happen, per the rules, yet in practice, it sometimes does happen anyway.

Comment: @donjuedo I was just adding a reference, not taking a stance. Kind of like "this post is being discussed on meta." Since then, the comment that referred to this post has been deleted. I'll leave the comment for the (IMO helpful) cross reference.

Comment: Good call.  It's good to know the rules, but code for reality ("defensive" coding).

Comment: So, case (1) only applies to `const_cast` and equivalents (which isn't mentioned by OP).  It appears that (3) is wrong and so is (4), except insofar as your compiler is not a C++ compiler.  Which leaves (2) -- accidentally removing a overload and replacing it with an override.  Also missing is the possibility that a function dispatches to a different override after you `const`ify a parameter; while such override switches shouldn't change functionality, sometimes existing code sucks.

Comment: All the more reason to test then. I've never come across a c++ compiler by this definition.

Comment: @Bathsheba clang?  gcc?

Comment: No, they all have bugs. I'm struggling to find why you find this so objectionable.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.
One possible problem with adding `const`s is possible undefined behaviour when changing the variable later (in a situation where the compiler can't prevent it anymore).
What if f is const here?

```
float f = 1.0;
//do something with f
readFromBinaryFile((char *)(&f), sizeof(f));
//do another something with f

//...

void readFromBinaryFile(char *c, size_t s)
{
    //... fill c
}
```